# BATCH - Replacing spaces in filename with %20 for curl

Tags: batch-file, curl

```
for /f %%n IN (new.txt) DO IF NOT EXIST "%current%\%%n" (
  ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 >nul
  setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set n=1n: =%%20!
  curl.exe --globoff -o "%current%\%%n" ""http://someserver.com/%%n ""
  ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >nul
)
```

I want to replace all spaces in %%n before handing it to curl to form a url to download the file specified in new.txt. I tried wrapping in double quotes and various other solutions to replace spaces, but none seem to have any effect. curl still doesnt form a proper url and cuts filenames before spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%n IN (new.txt) DO IF NOT EXIST "%current%\%%n" (
    set "n=%%n"
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "n=!n: =%%20!"
    curl.exe --globoff -o "%current%\%%n" --url "http://someserver.com/!n!"
    endlocal
)
```

You can not do string replacement in a `for` command replaceable parameter/variable, it is necessary to first copy it into a separate variable to operate with it

Also, by default, for command will split/tokenize the readed lines using spaces and tabs as delimiters, that is the reason for your file names being cut on the first space. Placing the `"delims="` option in the `for` command disables this behaviour.

Comment: I tried that, either its a bug in curl, but even though it now downloads the right filename it doesn't actually download the files. I have a bunch of 2kb files sitting in the specified location.

Comment: @user2280032, and, what is inside the 2kb files?

Comment: The 404 page is in those zip files. Which is odd, because the url seems fine now.

Comment: The issue was inside the filelistings, fixed it now.

Comment: Ran into another issue with my deletion of older files.

`for /f "delims=" %%r IN (new.txt) DO ATTRIB %%r +h

del /s /q "%current%\*.*"
del /s /q "%current%\*.*"

pause

for /f "delims=" %%t IN (new.txt) DO ATTRIB %%t -h`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the string replace syntax for a (FOR) parameter, this works only for variables.
But as you are in a code block you need to use delayed expansion.

Something like this should work

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%n IN (new.txt) DO IF NOT EXIST "%current%\%%n" (
  set "line=%%n"
  set "line=!line: =%%20!"
  curl.exe --globoff -o "%current%\%%n" ""http://someserver.com/!line! ""
)
```