# Change backslash to forward slash in windows batch file

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, slash

I'm trying to convert all backslashes () to forward slashes (/) in a variable which contains a file name and location. I've read about this and seen:

```
%variable:str1=str2%
```

and

```
set "var=%var:\=/%"
```

which I've attempted, but I'm obviously not getting it right.

Here is the relevant section of my .bat script:

```
FOR %%f IN ("E:\myfiles\app1\data\*.csv") DO (
  echo %%f  
  set "f=%%f:\=/%"
  echo %%f  
  echo.                 
)
```

The output show each filename listed twice.

i.e. this line:

```
set "f=f:\=/%"
```

is not doing what I want it to. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I meant [BATCH - Replacing spaces in filename with %20 for curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538894/batch-replacing-spaces-in-filename-with-20-for-curl)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`.

Your code contains two separate variables called `f`.

The first is the loop-control 'metavariable' called `f` and referenced by `%%f`.

The second is the common environment variable `f` which is established by the `set "f=..."` statement. This variable can be accessed by using `%f%` **but** within a `block`, it will appear to retain the value it had when the controlling `for` was parsed (in fact, any `%var%` is replaced at parse-time by the value of `var` **at that time**)

`metavariables` cannot be used in string-manipulation statements like substrings or substitutes, only common environment variables can be used for these operations, hence you need to assign the value of the metavariable `f` to the environment variable `f` and *then* perform the string-substitution task of the environment variable `f`.

The twist, of course, is that you must use `delayedexpansion` and the `!var!` syntax to access the modified value of an environment variable within a block.

So,

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for...%%f...do (
  echo %%f
  set "f=%%f"
  set "f=!f:\=/!"
  echo !f!
)
echo just for demonstration %f% !f! %%f
```

This sets the value of `f` in the required manner (of course, you could always change the name to avoid confusion...)

The last line is simply to show that the final value acquired by `f` can be accessed outside of the loop as either `%f%` or `!f!`, and that `%%f` is out-of-context and shown as `%f`.

Another way to do this without `delayedexpansion` is

```
for...%%f...do (
  echo %%f
  set "f=%%f"
  call set "f=%%f:\=/%%"
  call echo %%f%%
)
echo just for demonstration %f% !f! %%f
```

the difference being the use of `call` and doubling the `%`s, and the final line will show `!f!` as just that - a literal, since outside of `delayedexpansion` mode, `!` is just another character with no special meaning to `cmd`.

Comment: wow, a very comprehensive explanation, thanks so much! i had to read it a few times, but i think i'm getting it..!! windows batch script still looks really odd to me, i'm not sure i will ever really "get it"

Comment: I actually had to do the reverse: replace forward slash with backslash, but your explanation was perfect.

Comment: How to do the same but directly in the console?

Answer (score 109):

This will change the back-slashes to forward-slashes in a variable:

```
set "variable=E:\myfiles\app1\data\*.csv"
set "variable=%variable:\=/%"
echo "%variable%"
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly fine without the need of a loop. I just tried it myself (I didn't need the quotes, though).

Comment: Thanks @ThePersonWithoutC  - the quotes protect certain poison characters such as `&` and just make it more robust for odd situations.

Comment: Thank you, nicest solution here

Comment: How to do the same but directly in the console?

Comment: @ElieG. the above code worked fine for me directly in the console.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work for me:

```
echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR %%f IN ("C:\tools\workspace\*") DO (
  set old=%%f
  echo !old!
  set new=!old:\=/!
  echo !new!  
  echo.                 
)
```

Using a seperate variable rather than the loop variable makes the difference, along with enabling delayed expansion as the variable substittion syntex using the loop variable %%f dosn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

[Magoo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544690/45375) shows how to perform dynamic substitutions (via delayed expansion) inside a `for` loop's `(...)` block.

[foxidrive's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544993/45375) shows the general `cmd` syntax for performing literal, global string substitutions in variable values (also briefly shown in the question).

Let me complement these answer with a solution that **uses [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**:

Note:

- In the simple case at hand, this is overkill, and also performs worse than a pure `cmd` solution.
- However, the technique can be **helpful if you need *more sophisticated, regex-based* string substitutions**, via PowerShell's regex-based [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operator.

```
@echo off

:: Sample path.
Set inPath=C:\foo\bar

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (
  `powershell -noprofile -c "\"%inPath%\" -replace '\\', '/'"`
) do set "outPath=%%i"

echo %outPath%
```

The above yields:

```
C:/foo/bar
```

In-line variant, with the input path directly embedded and direct output of the transformed string:

```
C:\>powershell -noprofile -c "\"C:\foo\bar\" -replace '\\', '/'"
C:/foo/bar
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for change the backslashe to forward slashes in windows:

```
 typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
 tstring pathbasic = tstring(programdata) + _T("\\myfile.txt");
 std::replace(pathbasic.begin(), pathbasic.end(), _T('\\'), _T('/'));
```

Comment: This answer has no bearing on batch files