# calling a python line from a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script) that I can call a python script from a batch file.

What I want to do is calling a python line without using a script.

This is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
>> echo 'python.exe ''' "this/is/a/path".replace('/','\\')'''  '
```

would return `"this\\is\\a\\path"`

*Note: there is an easier way of doing what i'm trying to do in my example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542453/change-backslash-to-forward-slash-in-windows-batch-file) but this is not the question :)*

Comment: to run python in batch don't use `echo` but `python -c "command"` and you could use `print()` to display it.

Comment: C:\Python27>python.exe -c "print("helloworld")"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'helloworld' is not defined

Comment: `-c` option is for passing script as a string. Also remember to use one set of quotes for python inside and the other for the outside - otherwise bash will have problems matching them. For me it's just `python3 -c 'print("this/is/a/path".replace("/","\\"))'` in the shell.

Comment: You can't use `" "` inside `" "` - you have to use `' '` - ie. `"print( 'helloworld' )"` or `'print( "helloworld" )'`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, if you are just trying to run your python.exe then:

```
python python.exe
```

If you want to run perl style oneliners then:

```
echo '''print("this/is/a/path".replace("/","\\"))'''  >tmp_python_File && python tmp_python_File && rm tmp_python_File
```

Spits:

$> this\is\a\path

Comment: ```C:\Python27>echo '''print("this/is/a/path".replace("/","\\"))'''  >python.exe && python python.exe && rm python.exe
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.```

Comment: This answer overwrites the OP's python executable. I think he was just trying to call it, not create such a file.

Comment: oh wow why the downvote? ```What I want to do is calling a python line without using a script.```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-c` flag:

> Specify the command to execute (see next section).  This terminates the option list (following options are passed as arguments
>   to the command).

```
python -c '''print("this/is/a/path".replace("/","\\"))'''
> this\is\a\path
```

Comment: ```python -c '''print("this/is/a/path".replace("/","\\"))'''``` ... nothing happens

Comment: It works fine for me using both `python3` and `python2.7`. You don't have to run in in python console. Just run it in your terminal

Comment: @GuillaumeD this command is not called in python console but in system console/terminal or in script/batch. Don't you get any error message? Maybe you have to add `.exe` or `/full/path/to/python.exe`

Comment: that will open an interactive python cnsole, not keep him in bash

Answer (score 0):

this will work, thanks to @E.Serra approach.

```
echo print("this/is/a/path".replace("/","\\"))  > tmp_file && python tmp_file && rm tmp_file
```

-->

```
C:\Python27>echo print("this/is/a/path".replace("/","\\"))  >tmp_python_File && python tmp_python_File && rm tmp_python_File
this\is\a\path
```

Comment: life is unfair dude :)

Comment: but please correct your command line which is not working. be rigorous :)

Comment: the answer was correct, didn't know you already had a python.exe file which is why you could not overwrite it, thought python.exe was the name of your temporary file